# Get last row per group in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data below, and i want to get the last row per ***desc***

[image]

the result should be like this:

[image]

how can i do it in SQL, please note that database is oracle.

Comment: What should it return in case of the following data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=347972a7f9bcfb67722fc62da2bb1871

Comment: and what's your oracle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the expected result with the following query:

```
select * from tbl1
where id1 in (select max(id1) from tbl1 group by desc1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
select * from(
select id,desc1,row_number() over (partition  by desc1 order by id desc) rn from tov
)
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If in case of the following data

```
        ID DESCR
---------- ----------
         1 A
         2 A
         3 A
         4 B
         5 B
         6 B
         7 C
         8 C
         9 C
        10 A
        11 B
        12 C
```

you need to return

```
   ID_LAST DESCR
---------- ----------
         3 A
         6 B
         9 C
        10 A
        11 B
        12 C
```

You can use the following code (Oracle >=12 required):

```sql
select * 
from t
match_recognize (
   order by id
   measures
      last(id) as id_last,
      first(descr) as descr
   pattern (A B*)
   define 
      B as B.descr = A.descr and B.id=prev(id)+1
);
```

Full test case with sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9f951813d0338e4f3565c68f0069ae3

```sql
with t(id, descr) as (
select rownum id, column_value from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','A','B','C'))
)
select * 
from t
match_recognize (
   order by id
   measures
      last(id) as id_last,
      first(descr) as descr
   pattern (A B*)
   define 
      B as B.descr = A.descr and B.id=prev(id)+1
);
```

Results:

```
   ID_LAST DESCR
---------- ----------
         3 A
         6 B
         9 C
        10 A
        11 B
        12 C

6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(desc) over (order by id) as next_desc
      from t
     ) t
where next_desc is null or next_desc <> desc;
```

This has the advantage that it will return the last value for every adjacent set of `desc` values, even if the same `desc` value is repeated.

If you simply want the biggest id for each `desc`, use `group by`:

```
select desc, max(id)
from t
group by desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last id ordered by id for a particular desc, then the below would be elegant.

```
select  desc,  max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by id) as val 
from    t
group   by desc;
```